# Why does my content view inside my scrollview not respond

Tags: swift, scrollview

I have created a settings area inside a scrollview and set the content size of the scrollview according to my content view. 
When I run in the simulator or device with a small screen size I find that the views outside of the screens bounds are not responding to touches. I have a few switches that will work if they are just visible from the beginning. 
i have found a lot of other people having this problem but none of the solutions work for me. Trying to set the content view to the contentsize of the scrollview or vice versa is what i want to do because if i set "clip to bounds" I can clearly see that the content is not visible.
How can I set the whole scrollview to be responsive to touches.
im using storyboard auto layout but maybe I should set it all in code?

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 900)

    contentView.bounds.size = scrollView.contentSize
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
```

Comment: so are you try to do this thing by coding or autolayout

Comment: I have done all through autolayout

Comment: but set contentsize in code.

Comment: you have to set content size according to the your ContentView.size

Comment: But I think that  is my problem. How can I set my contentView to a size that is high enough?

Comment: Ive set my constraint to match the scrollview and then it should be just to set a large enough contentsize shouldn't it? If I try to set the content view to a certain height I get all sorts off conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

When using `UIScrollView`s together with auto layout, it is best to let autolayout figure out the content size. (This is also the easiest way to deal with scroll views in my opinion)

However, scroll views are inherently a little confusing when dealing with them at first. I do not know what your view looks like, but I have a few pointers that may help:

1. Anything that needs to scroll should go in some kind of container view. Based on your code above, I think that you've already done that with `contentView`.
2. Set all of your constraints from your scrollable content to that container view. Once you've done that set constraints of all edges from your container view to the scroll view that it is embedded in.
3. If you only want the user to be able to scroll vertically, create an equal widths constraint from the scroll view to the container view. (and if you want your user to only be able to scroll horizontally, set the two views to have equal heights).
4. Make sure that your scroll view is positioned correctly in it's super view and has the correct constraints to keep it in place.

This is pretty much what I do each time I have to use a scroll view. You don't have to set any content size in code, and everything is handled by auto layout (and thus supports rotation and other screen sizes without any extra work).

An example of these pointers in a xib can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4s0yqm5hjchp6n/View.xib?dl=0). And a blog post tutorial of this method can be found [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/).

*Edit: added a source*